# How to cycle displays in Mate desktop?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, display, display-settings, mate-desktop

On the Arch-based Antergos Linux, initially Gnome Shell desktop, I have installed Mate on a laptop that normally (in Windows, OpenSuse, Ubuntu) has a dedicated key to switch between displays, which here is not working.

Is there a default way of doing that? If not, how to set a key for that in Mate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `disper`.

In Ubuntu-beased systems:

> sudo apt-get install disper

In Arch-based systems it is in AUR.

Various commands available with this utility [HERE](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/disper.1.html).

The command to cycle between clone, extended, internal and external displays should be like this:

```
disper --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle
```

In that case, it would extend to the right. To cycle between the same options but extend to the left:

```
disper --direction=left --cycle-stages='-e : -c : -S : -s' --cycle
```

Disper will detect displays and use the maximal resolutions by default.

The command can be then associated to a short-key. To add that, go to System>Control Center>Keyboard Shortcuts, Add.