# How can I override xrandr selecting lower than the preferred resolution?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce, xrandr, display-settings

When I connect an external screen to my laptop using HDMI, the default resolution selected is not the maximum resolution - even though this resolution is listed under the available modes:

```
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
   1024x768       60.0 +   75.1     70.1     60.0  
   1920x1080      60.0*    59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      59.9  
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1440x900       75.0     59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1280x800       59.9  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1280x720       60.0     59.9  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     66.7     60.0     59.9  
   720x400        70.1
```

In this example, I've manually switched to `1920x1080`, but the initial resolution connected at was `1024x768`. This was chosen automatically by `xfce4-display-settings`; I suspect because of `xrandr` indicating it as the preferred resolution (see the `+` there)

Another monitor I connect to also chooses a suboptimal resolution. This means I have to keep on manually switching the resolutions.

How can I rather have `xrandr` choose the right (maximum resolution) mode straight away?

Note: I connect and disconnect from these screens frequently, so I'm looking for a way to get xrandr to behave as it should, not a custom `xorg.conf` setting that loads when I start the machine up. A custom script would be a second-best workaround, but as far as I can see `xrandr` should select the highest resolution, and I'm wondering why it doesn't

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94734/how-to-modify-the-default-setting-adopted-by-xrandr-when-connecting-an-external is similar but allows an xorg.conf and doesn't seem to have exactly the same problem